# Apache POI unable to detect hash formatted number

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I'm required to read the phone numbers uploaded via xls/xlsx into a Java String variable, as close as possible to what is being displayed on excel file.

So I have these data filled in:
[image]

As you can see, the actual value within the cell is `166609999`, and its formatted with `60#############`, so in the end we see `60166609999` appearing on the cell.

I'd like to capture the cell content as `60166609999` in String but so far I only manage to capture `166609999`, can anyone enlighten me what's wrong?

Note: If I change the format from `60############` to `60000000000`, I can capture `60166609999` without any issue, but the excel is uploaded via public site hence I can't enforce that.

The code is as simple as:

```
Cell cell = getTheCell(); // Got this after reading the sheets and rows
DataFormatter df = new DataFormatter();
String value = df.formatCellValue(cell);
// Here in value
// If format is 600000000, I can get 60166609999 (right)
// If format is 60#######, I get 166609999 (wrong)
```

Libraries I'm using:

- poi (poi) 3.17
- poi (poi-ooxml) 3.17
- poi (poi-ooxml-schemas) 3.17
- Java 7

Anybody knows what I need to do to be able to get it right?

Thank you.

Comment: Looks like an Apache POI bug to me. Any chance you could write a short junit unit test showing the problem, then open a bug in the Apache POI bugzilla?

Comment: @Gagravarr I've actually submitted a request here at https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=61638, is there anything I need to amend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is multidimensional.

At first, the number format `60############` cannot be applied usig `Java`. It leads to `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Malformed pattern "60############"` using [DecimalFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html#DecimalFormat(java.lang.String)).

But if the need is having each number prefixed with "60", then the `Excel` number formats `\6\0#` or `"60"#` should be possible and should be translated into the `DecimalFormat` pattern `'60'#`. But `apache poi`'s `DataFormatter` does not since it simply removes all quoting from the `Excel`'s format strings, which leads to `60#` which also is malformed pattern.

The problem is in [DataFormatter.java:671ff](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/poi/tags/REL_3_17_FINAL/src/java/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/DataFormatter.java?view=markup#l671).

I've patched this in my `MyDataFormatter` like so:

```
...
        // Now, handle the other aspects like 
        //  quoting and scientific notation
        for(int i = 0; i < sb.length(); i++) {
           char c = sb.charAt(i);
/*
            // remove quotes and back slashes
            if (c == '\\' || c == '"') {
                sb.deleteCharAt(i);
                i--;
*/
            // handle quotes and back slashes
            if (c == '\\') {
                sb.setCharAt(i, '\'');
                sb.insert(i+2, '\'');
                i+=2;
            } else if (c == '"') {
                sb.setCharAt(i, '\'');
            // for scientific/engineering notation
            } else if (c == '+' && i > 0 && sb.charAt(i - 1) == 'E') {
                sb.deleteCharAt(i);
                i--;
            }
        }

        formatStr = sb.toString();
        formatStr = formatStr.replace("''", ""); 
        return formatStr;
    }
...
```

Using this in this example:

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.*;

import java.io.FileInputStream;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;

class ExcelDataformatterExample {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  Workbook wb  = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream("ExcelExample.xlsx"));

  DataFormatter df = new DataFormatter();
  MyDataFormatter mydf = new MyDataFormatter();

  Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
  for (Row row : sheet) {
   for (Cell cell : row) {
    if (cell.getCellTypeEnum() == CellType.NUMERIC) {
     CellReference cellRef = new CellReference(row.getRowNum(), cell.getColumnIndex());
     System.out.println("Cell " + cellRef.formatAsString());

     System.out.print("Excel's data format string: ");
     String formatStr = cell.getCellStyle().getDataFormatString();
     System.out.println(formatStr);

     System.out.print("Value using poi's data formatter: ");
     Method cleanFormatForNumber = DataFormatter.class.getDeclaredMethod("cleanFormatForNumber", String.class); 
     cleanFormatForNumber.setAccessible(true); 
     String cleanFormatStr = (String)cleanFormatForNumber.invoke(df, formatStr);
     System.out.print("using poi's cleanFormatStr: ");
     System.out.print(cleanFormatStr + " result: ");
     String value = df.formatCellValue(cell);
     System.out.println(value);

     System.out.print("Value using my data formatter: ");
     cleanFormatForNumber = MyDataFormatter.class.getDeclaredMethod("cleanFormatForNumber", String.class); 
     cleanFormatForNumber.setAccessible(true); 
     cleanFormatStr = (String)cleanFormatForNumber.invoke(mydf, formatStr);
     System.out.print("using my cleanFormatStr: ");
     System.out.print(cleanFormatStr + " result: ");
     value = mydf.formatCellValue(cell);
     System.out.println(value);

    }
   }
  }
  wb.close();

 }

}
```

It leads to the following output, if values `199901234` are in cells `A1` to `A4` formatted in `Excel` as shown:

```
Cell A1
Excel's data format string: \60##########
Value using poi's data formatter: using poi's cleanFormatStr: 60########## result: 199901234
Value using my data formatter: using my cleanFormatStr: '6'0########## result: 199901234
Cell A2
Excel's data format string: \60000000000
Value using poi's data formatter: using poi's cleanFormatStr: 60000000000 result: 60199901234
Value using my data formatter: using my cleanFormatStr: '6'0000000000 result: 60199901234
Cell A3
Excel's data format string: "60"#
Value using poi's data formatter: using poi's cleanFormatStr: 60# result: 199901234
Value using my data formatter: using my cleanFormatStr: '60'# result: 60199901234
Cell A4
Excel's data format string: \6\0#
Value using poi's data formatter: using poi's cleanFormatStr: 60# result: 199901234
Value using my data formatter: using my cleanFormatStr: '60'# result: 60199901234
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the effort in solving this. I'm trying to digest the codes, but based on the results, are you implying that basically its not an easy task to globally support formats like "60####"? The good news is I actually don't require to detect decimal places and many other complicated formats, so if I can invoke the format methods like what you did, I think I can just duplicate the functions on my own, and just replace all '#' to '0', to get what I ultimately want?

Comment: @Chor Wai Chun: As said, the number format `60####` cannot be applied using Java's `DecimalFormat`. But it is also meaningless for me. Prefix all numbers with "6" and additionally put a 0 before numbers up to 4 digits length. What shall this mean? `Excel`'s formats `"60"#` or `\6\0#` which are: prefix all numbers with "60" are possible using my described patch.

Comment: its actually meaningless to the rest of the world haha, except in Malaysia where our country code is 60, hence we'd append it at the front of our number to get the international format. I can't control what kind of format my users would apply though, what I can do is just add in as much support as possible to their predicted input. So I guess replacing the '#' in their format to '0' before calling the format function is the best bet I have though..

Comment: In the end I just copied the whole DataFormatter class and do a `formatStr = formatStr.replace("#", "0");` in function `Format getFormat(Cell cell, ConditionalFormattingEvaluator cfEvaluator)`, sort of fixed my issue, thanks Axel =)

Comment: @Chor Wai Chun: Hm, I don't think that this is the way to go since it is too general. The pattern `#` is meaningful in some cases and should differ from `0` then and not simply always replaced by `0`. For example `#,##0.00` which means: put thousands separator if needed and formats 100 as 100.00 and 1000 as 1,000.00, would be then `0,000.00` and would format even 1 as 0,001.00 ;-).

Comment: Well I'm using this MyDataFormatter class only if the cell I'm reading is under column "phone number", and only if I see "60" at the front, so its only being used under controlled environment. For any other cases detected I'll fall back to the default DataFormatter class. So I guess that should be good enough, thanks for the headsup =)

Comment: Hi Axel, due to privacy reason, would you mind to edit or mask the number to something else? its my mistake to post my personal number and I recently found out its shown publicly on google, or do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: @Chor Wai Chun: done. If you had described the reason of your first editing a little bit better, then the misunderstanding would not had been necessary. I thought you doubt that my code results were right. Beeing a little bit more verbose is good for communication sometimes.